# what is the difference between Bhakti yoga and karma yoga?

Tags: karma, yoga, bhakti

what is the difference between Bhakti yoga and Karma yoga?

I know that both paths are almost the same, I mean both motives are the way to salvation

I want to know what is the major difference between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between karma yoga and bhakti yoga is that in karma yoga is not recommended for this yuga.
Karma yoga involves activities which are  performed in the consciousness of Sri Krishna and all fruits are dedicated to him.
Krishna says in Bhagvat Gita 3.9

> yajñārthāt karmaṇo 'nyatra
> loko    'yaṁ    karma-bandhanaḥ
> tad-arthaṁ  karma   kaunteya
> mukta-saṅgaḥ    samāca

> Work   done     as  a   sacrifice   for    Viṣṇu   has  to be  performed,   otherwise
> work     binds   one     to  this    material    world.  Therefore,  O   son     of  Kuntī,
> perform your    prescribed  duties  for His satisfaction,   and in  that    way you
> will    always  remain  unattached  and free    from    bondage.

Bhakti yoga is devotional service to Sri Krishna. No attachment to material desires, fruits of action. It's the superior form of yoga to approach Krishna very much recommend in Kali Yuga.
Krishna says in Bhagvat Gita 8.14. :

> ananya-cetāḥ   satataṁ
> yo  māṁ smarati nityaśaḥ
> tasyāhaṁ    sulabhaḥ    pārtha
> nitya-yuktasya  yoginaḥ

> For    one who remembers   Me  without deviation,  I   am  easy    to  obtain,
> O   son     of  Pṛthā,  because     of  his     constant    engagement in   devotional
> service.

Comment: Why bakthi yoga not recommended?

Comment: Bhakti yoga is very much recommended. It is karma yoga which is not recommended in this age of Kali @Rahul

Comment: Can u pls add source for bhakti yoga recommendations?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake, but why is karma yoga not recommended.

Comment: Karma yoga is not recommended in this yuga cuz we are very attached to desires of actions we perform and we can't let go of it. In Kali Yuga all of us are very greedy and only live for sense gratification because of which our abilities to concentrate on krishna is very difficult. Bhakti yoga is chanting name of Krishna which is yuga Dharma proposed by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu( Krishna as his own devotee) it's the easiest way to approach and understand Krishna.